# bootstrap styling not working with django floppyforms

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms, django-floppyforms

I am switching from Django Crispy Forms to Floppy Forms, but my desired Bootstrap styling appears to be lost; now it just looks like a plain unstyled form.

**Crispy**

Here is what I had with Crispy Forms's Bootstrap template pack:

[image]

Here was the generated source:

```
<div id="div_id_sent_amount" class="form-group has-error">
        <label for="id_sent_amount" class="control-label  requiredField">How much would you like to give?
        <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="controls ">
        <select class="select form-control" id="id_sent_amount" name="sent_amount"><option value="" selected="selected">---------</option><option value="0.00">$0.00</option><option value="0.05">$0.05</option><option value="0.10">$0.10</option></select>
        <span id="error_1_id_sent_amount" class="help-block"><strong>This field is required.</strong></span></div>
</div>
```

**Floppy**

Here is what I get with Floppy using the Bootstrap layout [here](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bootstrap.html).

[image: enter link description here]

Here is the generated source:

```
<div class="form-group error">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="id_sent_amount">Sent amount <span class="required">*</span>:</label>

        <div class="controls col-sm-8  field-sent_amount">
            <select id="id_sent_amount" name="sent_amount">
                 <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
                 <option value="0.00">$0.00</option>
                 <option value="0.05">$0.05</option>
                 <option value="0.10">$0.10</option>
            </select>
            <ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>

        </div><!--- .controls -->
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

floppyforms just provides easier layout and widget control, it does not automatically enable bootstrap styling.

For that, you have to do a bit of work as detailed in [the documentation](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bootstrap.html).

In summary, you have to create these templates:

1. `floppyforms/templates/floppyforms/layouts/bootstrap.html`
2. `floppyforms/templates/floppyforms/rows/bootstrap.html`
3. `floppyforms/templates/floppyforms/layouts/default.html`
4. `floppyforms/templates/floppyforms/errors.html`

Fill them with bootstrap-specific styling (examples are provided [in the documentation](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bootstrap.html)).

Keep in mind the examples are for an older version of bootstrap; you might want to update the templates with the [current version of bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).

You can edit the templates by hand to bring them up to date, or use [`django-floppyforms-bootstrap3`](https://github.com/grundleborg/django-floppyforms-bootstrap3) which does exactly what it says - updates the templates for bootstrap3 compatibility.

Comment: Hi Burhan, I already did that. I see some Bootstrap classes are being applied to my form, like `class="col-sm-4"`, but the look is still not the way it was before.

Comment: Did you forget to include the bootstrap css?

Comment: I have it (`static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`), and the rest of the page is being styled with bootstrap, it's just the form that isn't.

Comment: You have a class `field-sent_amount` what is this? Its not from the default bootstrap CSS.

Comment: That's generated by Floppy's `rows/bootstrap.html` (http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bootstrap.html). See it says:  `field-{{ field.name }}`

Comment: Ah, that seems to be it! Currently trying to find a version for Bootstrap3, will give an update.